# Добавить текущую дату в имя файла

Tags: время, sql

Доброго времени суток! Я собираюсь настроить создание бэкапов через скрипт на SQL 2008 R2, скрипт есть, но у меня возник вопрос. Вот скрипт

```
BACKUP DATABASE [mybase1] TO DISK = N'c:\sqlbackup\mybase1.bak' WITH INIT, NOUNLOAD, NAME = N'MyBase1 Backup', NOSKIP, STATS = 10, NOFORMAT;
```

`'c:\sqlbackup\mybase1.bak'` - это имя файла бэкапа, как мне сделать так что бы перед расширением вставала текущая дата (без двоеточия)!? Например `c:\sqlbackup\mybase270112.bak` И если можно, то пример кода!

Answer (score 1):

лучше будет изменить порядок yy mm dd

```
N'c:sqlbackupmybase'+REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 2), '.', '')+'.bak'

DECLARE @path VARCHAR(260)
SET @path = N'd:003sqlbackupmybase'+REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 2), '.', '') +'.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE [Ut_demo] TO DISK = @path  WITH INIT, NOUNLOAD, NAME = N'UT_demo Backup', NOSKIP, STATS = 10, NOFORMAT;
```

Comment: Получил вот такую строчку: BACKUP DATABASE [Ut_demo] TO DISK = N'd:\003\sqlbackupmybase'+REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, getdate(), 2), '.', '')+'.bak' WITH INIT, NOUNLOAD, NAME = N'UT_demo Backup', NOSKIP, STATS = 10, NOFORMAT;

Comment: И вот такие ошибки:!
Сообщение 102, уровень 15, состояние 1, строка 1
Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "+".
Сообщение 319, уровень 15, состояние 1, строка 1
Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слова "with". Если эта инструкция является обобщенным табличным выражением, предложением xmlnamespaces или предложением в контексте отслеживания изменений, предыдущую инструкцию необходимо завершить точкой с запятой.

Comment: параметром должен быть литерал или переменная а не переменная

Comment: ... а не выражение

Comment: СПАСИБО! Всё работает!

Answer (score 0):

А если динамически выполнить?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Maintenance Plan вместо самописного кода. Задача не такого уровня, чтобы через разработку ее решать.